# Word for someone who is helpful but not very nice about it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe this kind of person.

e.g. "*Hey dude what's the square root of 9 again?*

"*Oh my God are you really asking me that? It's 3... you idiot."*

Comment: Cantankerous: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cantankerous

Comment: Here, taken for granted (not even a 'please').

Comment: grouch, grump, curmudgeon.  Although if someone asked me what the square root of 9 was -- again! -- I wouldn't be polite either.

Comment: Do you want an adjective, a noun, maybe a verb...? If you include a sample sentence with a ___ where the target word would go, it will be clearer what you're asking for. (This is technically required for single-word-requests.)

Answer (score 3):

**Condescending**

> behave as if one is [...] descending from a superior position

or **patronizing**

> treat with an apparent kindness that betrays a feeling of superiority

or **snobby**

> condescendingly patronizingly rude.

Answer (score 3):

***grudging***, defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grudging)

> done, given, or allowed unwillingly, reluctantly, or sparingly •
>   Grudging compliance

*Grudging* doesn't fit your example sentence well; *justifiably exasperated* fits your example sentence better. (Who doesn't know the square root of nine?).  *Grudging* does fit the broader meaning of your question. For example:

> Hey, dude, I overslept and missed English class. Can I scan your notes
>   into my computer?
>
> Oh god, not again! OK but be quick about it; what do you think I am --
>   your Personal Assistant?  Get an alarm clock, will you?

Answer (score 0):

Sarcastic? Ironical? Obtuse. You have two emotions in that sentence; aid and animosity. So although they are being helpful they are nonetheless being rude. So at the end of that sentence you could add: 'he replied sarcastically'.

Answer (score 0):

> **Efficious**:
>
> 1. The state of being aggressively productive.
> 2. Effectively mean; bitchy beyond reproach; cuntlike
>
> — https://webpen.blog/2007/07/04/webpentionary/

Answer (score 0):

In terms of styles used in writing a novel, you could use the words "benevolent yet belligerent".

Comment: What is a bellingerant?

Comment: -To be hostile, aggressive, or quarrelsome.https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/belligerent

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the individual is **[churlish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/churlish)** or that they made a churlish remark:

> marked by a lack of civility or graciousness

Google's definition is a bit clearer and better suited for this situation:

> rude in a mean-spirited and surly (bad-tempered/unfriendly) way

Example:

> "Hey dude what's the square root of 9 again?
>
> "Oh my God are you really asking me that?" he remarked churlishly. "It's 3...you idiot."